# Django email attatchment

Tags: django

Django email attatch issues.

I am trying to attach a PDF file and send an email in django using amazon email service 
how can i attach and send mail using this service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: http://hmarr.com/2011/jan/26/using-amazons-simple-email-service-ses-with-django/

In summary, install boto and django-ses:

```
pip install boto
pip install django-ses
```

add your amazon access key to settings.py

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'YOUR-ACCESS-KEY-ID'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'YOUR-SECRET-ACCESS-KEY'
```

and tell django to use SES for its default email backend, also put this in settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
```

and then to send email with attachment, see here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#the-emailmessage-class

You need to create an EmailMessage object, add the list of files to the .attachments attribute, and .send() it.